# Selenium IDE issue on Mozilla firefox: table view is not available with this format

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to work with the Selenium IDE on Mozilla Firefox (version 55.0.3).

The issue is that for some reason I cannot see any action I perform on the browser (such as waitForTitle, verify title etc.). They should be displayed in the Selenium IDE I have installed as a developer tool (in the table).

Also, when trying to click on something in the IDE, I get the following error message:

> There was an unexpected error. Msg: TypeError: window.editor.infoPanel is undefined Url: chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-ide.xul, line: 1, column: 1 onclick@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-ide.xul:1:1

Most likely, this is related to why I cannot see any action in the table.

This problem really bugs me, because I Googled the exact error message and was unable to find a proper solving-system to deal with it. I mention that my clipboard format is already set to HTML.

All suggestions are welcome, and thank you in advance for taking the time to read this.

[image: Basic view of Selenium IDE]

[image: Error message I get when trying to click something in the Selenium IDE]

Comment: check IED campatible with your firefox,  try change IDE or firefox version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Selenium IDE is no more supported and it may be a issue with latest firefox version. If you really want to use it then go back to a older version of firefox

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it completely, installed Mozilla 54.0.1 and it works like a charm, now am finally able to do my thing. But how can I prevent Mozilla from updating itself? Asking because I want to make sure it won't update sometime in the future behind closed doors and cause troubles for me with their newest support rules.

Comment: Go to `about:config` and search for `app.update.auto` and `app.update.enabled`. Set both of them to false.